# Unity Ads doesn't show any ads when when my game goes live.. but test ads are working fine.. dashboard shows request but there is no impressions

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads, impressions

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mixtP.png## Heading ##